# How does the following class have to look for desired output?

Tags: javascript, class

```
class Answer{
  //insert code here
}

let answer = new Answer();

console.log( +answer === 20 ); //this should return true
```

What do I have to write in my class in order to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh yes, good old valueOf. The valueOf property when defined converts an object into a number when called upon.

In your situation all you have to do is create a valueOf function in your Answer class and have it return 20. e.g.

```
class Answer{

   valueOf () {
       return 20;
   }
}

let answer = new Answer();

console.log( +answer === 20 ); //this should re
```

Hope that helps!